# select what is currently tabbed over javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Hi I have a list of things in the following format

```
<ul>
    <li value="5">5</li>
    <li value="4">4</li>
    <li value="8">8</li>
    <li value="3">3</li>
    <li value="9">9</li>
</ul>
```

When the user tabs over the li tags by literally hitting the "tab" button I want to console.log or alert the value of the li tag...(I actually want to execute another function using this value, but I'm having trouble doing the actual selecting of the value by the fact that it is tabbed over). Something like getElementById or getElementByClass would be ideal..

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: The first thing you probably want to do is add a `tabindex` attribute to the elements so that pressing Tab can actually select them.

Comment: Yeah I already have that working. I can tab through them. The above is just a simplified version.

Comment: In the future, sometimes posting a version of your problem that's __too__ simplified can cause problems or require unnecessary responses :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afocus) pseudo class.  That will work in CSS and jQuery.

```
function getSelectedListItem() {
    return $("li:focus");
}
```

Or, better yet, just handle the [`focus` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onfocus):

```
$("li").focus(function(){
    var listItem = this;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to log to the console during or after the tab event, you can use the jquery shortcuts `blur()` and `focus()`to trigger a log to the console.

**useful:**
http://api.jquery.com/blur/, http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Answer (score 0):

To be sure it will work just when you trigger the event, you need to reference the event target, because in the listener function the *real focus* wasn't applied yet:

```
function getSelectedListItem(e) {
   alert($(e.target).html());  
}

//Working!
$('li').on('focus',getSelectedListItem);

//This will not work
//$('li').on('focus',getSelectedListItemBySelector);

function getSelectedListItemBySelector() {
   alert($("li:focus").html());  
}
```

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yzS22/1/) explains better why...